# Finding and counting capital letters

Tags: java, string, methods, replace

I've written a method to check a string for capital letters, and if it finds one int count is increased by 1. But when I test the method im being told that dividing by 0 is not allowed. It shouldnt be 0.. can anyone shed light on this?

```
    public final boolean findIfCaps(String msg)
    {
        int count=0;
        msg = msg.replaceAll("\\W","");
        for(int x=0;x<msg.length();x++){
            if(Character.isUpperCase(msg.charAt(x)))
                count++;
        }
        double percent = count/msg.length();
        if(percent>0.5)
           return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What message are you testing this on? Also, if you step through with a debugger, what's `msg` after the call to `replaceAll()`?

Comment: What are you passing into `findIfCaps` when the error occurs? If it is only made of non-word characters, `msg = msg.replaceAll("\\W","")` will turn `msg` into the empty string, which has length 0.

Comment: You don't need this `replaceAll` for your task.

Comment: All you need to check msg.length(). Why and how this is zero

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an explicit check if `msg.length() > 0`. It can be an empty string, which would lead to the exception.

(You can also omit the `replaceAll(..)` part, it doesn't help you with finding the number of capital letters)

Comment: Either that or you have to fix whatever bug is causing the `msg` to be of 0 length

Comment: it can possibly be an empty message - a check is needed somewhere

Comment: `it can possibly be an empty message`  That sounds like an assumption.  If `msg` has no business being empty, than and empty message is an error state, in which case you actually want to throw an exception.

Comment: sure - that's what the explicit check is for :) he can decide whether it should mean "false" or an exception, but the check is needed anyway

Comment: msg will never ever be empty or it wouldnt be passed. i guess the replace all could be messing with the length but ive only gotten the exception on alphanumeric characters. Anyways, ill try adding the check. Thanks!